# Symfony helpers and database

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I use symfony 1.4.11 with doctrine. I have helper:

```
function filterwords($text){

    $filterWords=array ('some','filter','words');
     $filterCount = sizeof($filterWords);
        for($i=0; $i<$filterCount; $i++){
        $text = preg_replace('/\b'.$filterWords[$i].'\b/ie',"str_repeat('*',strlen('$0'))",$text);
                                         }
        return $text;
                               }
    }
```

All works fine. But I want to make module, that administrator can add words to filter from backend. Is it possible to transfer data from the database to varaible  **$filterWords** I have next schema:

```
Filter:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: filter
  columns:
    word: {type: string(255), notnull: true}
```

I can make in helper something like this, and get word what I need :

```
 $record = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Filter')->getWordFilter();

 foreach ($record as $filter )

   {
 echo  $filter ->getWord();
    }
```

But I do not how to implement it im my function...

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not now is it correct, but it is work.

```
 function filterwords($text){
  $record = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Filter')->getWordFilter();//

   foreach ($record as $filter )
   {
        $filterWords[] =  $filter->getWord();
    }
         $filterCount = sizeof($filterWords);
        for($i=0; $i<$filterCount; $i++){
        $text = preg_replace('/\b'.$filterWords[$i].'\b/ie',"str_repeat('*',strlen('$0'))",$text);
                                         }
        return $text;
                               }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass `$filterwords` in as a variable:

```
function filterwords($text, $filterwords)
{
   //etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
field = the column name that contains a value you're searching by.

$record = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Words')->findOneByField($value);
$filterWords = $record->getWord();
```

Comment: Thank you,but I'm not sure if this is what I need.. I can make `$record = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Words')->findOneBy('word','some filter word');` But I need to get all data from database and pass it to my $filterWords, but maybe I'm wrong...